# java.lang.ClassCastException, DeepNodeListImpl cannot be cast

Tags: java, xml, classcastexception, nodelist

here is my code :

```
 public void Login() {  
    try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = builderfactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        File path = new File("src/dataPengguna/dataPengguna.xml");

        Document doc = db.parse(path);

        Element pengguna = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("pengguna");

        NodeList list = pengguna.getElementsByTagName("user");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Element user =  (Element) list.item(i);
            Node username =   user.getElementsByTagName("username").item(i);
            Node password =   user.getElementsByTagName("password").item(i);

            if(loginuser.getText().equals(username.getTextContent()) 
               && loginpass.getText().equals(password.getTextContent())){ 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "welcome");
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
    }
```

here is my xml :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <pengguna>

         <user>
         <nama>septian</nama>
         <username>septiansykes</username>
         <password>1234</password>
         <status>belumpinjam</status> 
         </user>    

         <user>
         <nama>koko</nama>
         <username>kokosan</username>
         <password>12er</password>
         <status>belumpinjam</status> 
         </user>

         <user>
         <nama>tamrin</nama>
         <username>tamrincs</username>
         <password>gt234</password>
         <status>belumpinjam</status> 
         </user>

    </pengguna>
```

and here is my error :

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException:com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
```

i try to get the element at the xml file, i want to check the element username and password, but there is an error about the cast class, it's seem difficult for me,... thanks before

Answer (score 6):

This is the problem:

```
Element pengguna = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("pengguna");
```

[`getElementsByTagName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't return a single element - it returns multiple elements. You probably want something like:

```
NodeList penggunas = doc.getElementsByTagName("pengguna");
if (penggunas.getLength() != 1) {
    // Handle this - e.g. throw an exception
}
Element pengguna = (Element) penggunas.item(0);
```

EDIT: Later, you've got a bug here:

```
Node username =   user.getElementsByTagName("username").item(i);
Node password =   user.getElementsByTagName("password").item(i);
```

This should be:

```
Node username =   user.getElementsByTagName("username").item(0);
Node password =   user.getElementsByTagName("password").item(0);
```

You're already within the `user` element - so you *always* want the first `username` and `password` elements within that element. Otherwise you're asking for the second `username` element within the second `user` element, the third `username` element within the third `user` element etc. The numbering is relevant to the element that you're in, not some global count.

Comment: +1 I won't add code to my answer as yours contains valid one to solve the problem :)

Comment: yeah its solved, but the algorithm for(i=0;i<penggunas.item;i++) only the item(0) well defined, the other item doesn't defined, so if i login with username e.g "kokosan" and password "12er" the system return nullpointerexception

Comment: @zeptyan: That's because you've got another bug - I'll edit my answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementByTagName()` returns a `NodeList` and you try to cast it to an `Element`. This line is incorrect and will give you the `ClassCastException`:

```
Element pengguna = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("pengguna");
```